# how to apply div class to my css written in cutom.css in woocommerce

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to apply it to div tag of product image for a woocomerce site.

I think its applied using php(from woocomerce plugin) but I am new so have no idea.

```
///in css


.panel .panel-overlay, .panel .overlay-background{height: 60px; padding:10px;}
.panel .overlay-background{background: #222;}
.panel .panel-overlay{color: white; font-size: 0.7em;}




//want to add this to div


<li><img src="" alt="" />
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2>Image Title goes here</h2>
              <p>information about the image.<br />

            </div>
</li>
```

Can anyone direct me

Comment: You can copy woocommerce templates to your theme folder and edit the templates there. Check [this tutorial](http://uploadwp.com/overriding-woocommerce-template-files/)

Comment: Can you include the code and relevant config you've written so far?

Comment: @AkashK. How would I know which php is to be moddified?

Comment: And how do we add element to html in woocommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change template from a plugin you should at least know basics of

1. Wordpress template Structure
2. Wordpress theme editing/development

To edit template of your Woocommerce Shop follow these steps:

1. Find out the template which you want to edit. (`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates`)

Your case: Detect whether its a Single Product Page (`single-product.php`) or Archive Product Page or Shop Page (`archive-product.php`) as product image is usually on these pages. There are some nested templates included inside these template files. Check if the part you want to edit is not in some nested template. If it is open that nested template file and see where you want to make the modifications.

2. Once you've found the template where you want to make the changes. Copy the template from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` to `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce`. If the template is inside any other folder in woocommmerce plugin create that folder too. You have to keep the directory structure same.
3. Make the changes in the template which you've copied to your theme inside woocommerce folder.

This template will override the default woocommerce template.

**Note:** In case you are using any woocommerce enabled theme. The template must be present in your theme folder already. Take a backup of theme before you edit template in that theme.

Comment: @Shagayag - Its still in use in version 2.4.7

Comment: Sorry but i cant see any DIV tags :( As shown in image in question, I want to set a transparent png in front of jpeg image

Comment: @Shagayag - Did you even check the template? Try making some efforts by yourself. The code is clearly from `single-product/product-image.php`